# ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = character varying

Tags: postgresql

This is my query where i am getting below error..

```
SELECT incident_id, incident_name, incident_desc, incident_status,  
       root_cause_level_1, 
       root_cause_level_2, remediate_proj_name, remediate_proj_desc, remediate_proj_phase, start_date, end_date
FROM incident_details 
  INNER JOIN complain_details ON complain_details.complaint_id = incident_details.incident_id;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric = character varying
> LINE 3: ...complain_details ON complain_details.complaint_id = incident...
>                                                             ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

I have try to type cast not work.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: one column is a numeric column, the other a varchar. Postgres won't let you compare apples to oranges. If those columns should contain the same values (because you use them for joining) they should have the same data type (probably integer judging by the "id" suffix - neither numeric nor varchar)

Comment: Show us the cast you tried that didn't work and explain _why_ the cast didn't work

Comment: SELECT incident_id, incident_name, incident_desc, incident_status, root_cause_level_1, 
root_cause_level_2, remediate_proj_name, remediate_proj_desc, remediate_proj_phase, start_date, end_date
  FROM incident_details INNER JOIN complain_details ON CAST(complain_details.complaint_id AS VARCHAR) = incident_details.incident_id;   I am try to type cast like that where my complaint_id  numeric and incident_id varchar.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments **[edit]** your question instead (by clicking on the [edit] link below it)